# how to take json from veriable in d3 chart

Tags: json

I am using D3 to plot bubble chart using data in json format to plot bubble chart
My json format is like:`{"children":[
     {"name":"1","size":0.5},
     {"name":"3","size":0.3636},
     {"name":"4","size":0.5652},
     {"name":"5","size":19.5556},
     {"name":"6","size":1.037},
     {"name":"7","size":0.7048},
     {"name":"8","size":2.2593},
     {"name":"9","size":13.7407},
     {"name":"10","size":4.2222},
     {"name":"11","size":2.6667},
     {"name":"12","size":0.7037},
     {"name":"13","size":20.6296},
     {"name":"14","size":17.7037},
     {"name":"15","size":2.1481},
     {"name":"16","size":3.4815},
     {"name":"17","size":0.1852},
     {"name":"18","size":0.087},
     {"name":"19","size":15.68}
     ]}`

I am accessing this json as:

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
  .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

now i want to access from veriable
var datasource=`{"children":[
     {"name":"1","size":0.5},
     {"name":"3","size":0.3636},
     {"name":"4","size":0.5652},
     {"name":"5","size":19.5556},
     {"name":"6","size":1.037},
     {"name":"7","size":0.7048},
     {"name":"8","size":2.2593},
     {"name":"9","size":13.7407},
     {"name":"10","size":4.2222},
     {"name":"11","size":2.6667},
     {"name":"12","size":0.7037},
     {"name":"13","size":20.6296},
     {"name":"14","size":17.7037},
     {"name":"15","size":2.1481},
     {"name":"16","size":3.4815},
     {"name":"17","size":0.1852},
     {"name":"18","size":0.087},
     {"name":"19","size":15.68}
     ]}`
I have tried like:

```
JSON.parse("dataSource", function(error, root) {
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
  .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

but unable to get result where i am going wrong.please reply me.

Thanks
prashansa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datasource` is variable not string

so try this

```
JSON.parse(dataSource, function(error, root) {
```

EDITED

```
var dataSource = '{"children":...'; //JSON.parse needed
//so your code would be
JSON.parse(dataSource, function(error, root) {

var dataSource = {"children":...}; //JSON.parse not needed
//so your code would be
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(bubble.nodes(classes(dataSource))
            .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for your reply I tried it but still not getting result

Comment: see my edited answer and check what are your looking for

Comment: @user3090158 if you think this answer is right,than you can mark it right. so it can be useful for other user.

Comment: when I am using 'var dataSource = '{"children":...'; //JSON.parse needed
//so your code would be
JSON.parse(dataSource, function(error, root) {' it's not working but second approach 'var dataSource = {"children":...}; //JSON.parse not needed
//so your code would be
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(bubble.nodes(classes(dataSource))
            .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; })) 'working fine